# Autocomplete/Drop-down feature not functioning properly on QT 5.7.0

Tags: qt, autocomplete, qt5, qt-creator, intellisense

I am using QT 5.7.0 on Arch Linux. I am a beginner at Qt and hence I am watching some tutorial videos.

What I find odd and annoying is that the person in video is using the same main version but gets all the Intellisense auto-complete feature working perfectly. But on the other hand , mine is not giving options to all the Options.

For example,

When he types "SIGNAL", he gets a lot of drop-down options to choose from. But I don't .

[image]

On my Qt:
[image]

This does not happen everywhere. In some functions or variables, I do get the drop-down . But I don't get it for some set of keywords : like SIGNAL,SLOT etc..

Even when I get the options, its too few compared to the Video.

I have enabled this feature in my settings :
[image]

Please help me solve this problem. I really need this feature as I am learning Qt.

Comment: I am not using Visual Studio. Just Qt-creator. I have qt5-examples and doc installed.

Comment: Have you tried pressing ctrl+space while writing?

Comment: @Mike Yes, I have tried pressing Ctrl+Space. It does not work all the time. Same as above. It works only for few keywords.